# NullPointerException in InstantRunNotificationTask when trying to run project in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-instant-run, instant-run

I'm getting an error in Android Studio whenever I run my project that brings up these details:

```
null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.tools.idea.run.tasks.InstantRunNotificationTask.<init>(InstantRunNotificationTask.java:63)
    at com.android.tools.idea.fd.InstantRunBuildAnalyzer.getNotificationTask(InstantRunBuildAnalyzer.java:178)
    at com.android.tools.idea.run.AndroidLaunchTasksProvider.getTasks(AndroidLaunchTasksProvider.java:120)
    at com.android.tools.idea.run.LaunchTaskRunner.run(LaunchTaskRunner.java:102)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:726)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:176)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:556)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:501)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:66)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:163)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:137)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$2.run(ApplicationImpl.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I've tried reinstalling the SDK, the plugin and restarting everything. Not sure what else could be going wrong.

Comment: Not quite sure why this question is getting negative vote? I think the problem is well defined. I do not know whether the question is duplicate or not. If it is a duplicate, then please flag the question as duplicate and leave the question that has the answer in it. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Go to `Preferences`.
- Then under `Build, Execution, Deployment` section you will have the `Instant Run` section.
- **Uncheck** the `Enable Instant Run...` checkbox and then try building your project again.

Comment: This worked like a charm. Is there anything the instant run might be needed for in the future? And if so, any idea how to run the app with it enabled?

Comment: Glad to know that helped!

Comment: Glad to know that it helped! Yes you might need instant run in future. Update the latest version of SDK, build-tools and emulator images.

Comment: But what if I want use Instant run!

Comment: The instant run feature is not stable yet in my opinion. In some cases, you might not be able to use instant run.